# Canvas image cropping issue. Is the image too big?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, image-processing, html5-canvas

Yesterday, I already asked a question about this issue. I had no idea, however, what the problem was. Today I know it is something about the sourceWidth in the drawImage command:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth,
        sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
```

So I've descided to open a new topic and delete the old one.

But let me start at the beginning:
I'm trying to implement a homemade "zoom function" on a historical document (see image below). It works fine in Firefox, but it does not in any other browser.

[Firefox behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE9GT.jpg)

In Chrome or Internet Explorer it looks like this. The zoom-area is empty.

[Chrome behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE0qV.jpg)

An image is displayed, if I just draw it, without any cropping:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
```

But if I try to use the crop function (explained at html5canvastutorials.com) with all needed values (**sourceWidth = 1800**), I cannot see the image in my canvas.
Interestingly, if I change the **sourceWidth** to a low value like **400** or lower the image is drawn. An `imageObj.onload` doesn't change anything, as well as the adaption of the **original image size** (e.g. to *600x900*) or the **width of the canvas**.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution for my problem. It's about the `sourceWidth` and the `destX`. I think it was a trivial problem, but I didn't know about this condition.  It's about the following command:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth,
        sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
```

You have to make sure that `imageWidth - destX = sourceWidth`, if sourceWidth is greater, Chrome, IE ... won't draw your image. I don't know why Firefox can cope with it.

Here is a numerical example:
`imageWidth = 1024`, you want to cut off 200px of the left side, so `destX = 200` and `sourceWidth < 824`.

Comment: Please avoid large lines, add a line break.